# React Native picker issue

Tags: javascript, react-native

Am unable to set Picker in middle of the screen on iPhone even querying in google and Udemy I did not get a solution. Please Help me guys. I hope you guys will help me in this React Native picker issue. Am trying to solve this issue from last week but couldn't do so guys please help me.

EmployeeCreate

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Picker, Text } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { employeeUpdate } from '../actions';
import { Card, CardSection, Input, Button } from './common';

class EmployeeCreate extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Card>
        <CardSection>
          <Input
            label="Name"
            placeholder="Jane"
            value={this.props.name}
            onChangeText={value => this.props.employeeUpdate({ prop: 'name', value })}
          />
        </CardSection>

        <CardSection>
          <Input
            label="Phone"
            placeholder="555-555-555"
            value={this.props.phone}
            onChangeText={value => this.props.employeeUpdate({ prop: 'phone', value })}
          />
        </CardSection>

        <CardSection style={‌{ flexDirection: 'column', }}>
          <Text style={styles.pickerTextStyle}>Shift</Text>
          <Picker
            style={‌{ flex: 1 }}
            selectedValue={this.props.shift}
            onValueChange={value => this.props.employeeUpdate({ prop: 'shift', value })}
          >
          <Picker.Item label="Monday" value="Monday" />
          <Picker.Item label="Tuesday" value="Tuesday" />
          <Picker.Item label="Wednesday" value="Wednesday" />
          <Picker.Item label="Thursday" value="Thursday" />
          <Picker.Item label="Friday" value="Friday" />
          <Picker.Item label="Saturday" value="Saturday" />
          <Picker.Item label="Sunday" value="sunday" />
          </Picker>
        </CardSection>

        <CardSection>
          <Button>
            Create
          </Button>
        </CardSection>
      </Card>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  pickerTextStyles: {
    fontSize: 18,
    paddingLeft: 20
  }
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const { name, phone, shift } = state.employeeForm;
  return { name, phone, shift };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { employeeUpdate })(EmployeeCreate);
```

CardSection

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

const CardSection = (props) => {
  return (
    <View style={[styles.containerStyle, props.style]}>
      {props.children}
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = {
  containerStyle: {
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    padding: 5,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    borderColor: '#ddd',
    position: 'relative'
  }
};

export { CardSection };
```

Screenshot :

[image: React Native Picker Issue]

Comment: Try removing `flex: 1` at the styling for the picker. Add `justifyContent: "center"` to the `CardSection` style.

Comment: I changed it but everything has gone except login entry fields and shift

Answer (score 0):

Picker is not in the center because on left side you have shift text. If you want to make picker in the center then you have to set width of the picker.

Try changing the width of the picker = width of screen - 2 * (width of text)

If it is not possible to change the width of a picker then set the left margin of the picker = negative value of width of the shift text

and increase the left padding to picker text value so that shift text will not overlap picker value